# Putting images in java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, draw

I've been trying for a while to load an image into this JFrame for it to display it without success. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main extends JPanel{

Bird bird = new Bird(this);

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    bird.paint(g2D);
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Birds");
    Main game = new Main();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while(true){
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
}
```

This is my Bird Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Bird {
    private static final Image sprite = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bird.jpeg");
    private static final int DIAMETER = 30;
    double g = 0.12, vy = 0, xo = 100, yo = 10;
    private Main game;

    public Bird(Main game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawImage(sprite, 30, 30, game);
    }
}
```

When I run this nothing shows up onscreen, but if I place a g.fillOval instruction I do get a circle in the panel. Help much appreciated, please.

Answer (score 3):

There are a cascade of issues, first...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    bird.paint(g2D);
}
```

You're overriding `paint`, it is highly unrecommended to do so, instead, it is recommended that you override `paintComponent` instead.

Another problem is...

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bird.jpeg");
```

The problem with this is `getImage(String)` expects that the value you pass it refers to a file on the file system.  In most cases, this is not true and the image is stored as an embedded resource, in which use you would need to use something more like...

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Bird.class.getResource("bird.jpeg"));
```

or

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Bird.class.getResource("/bird.jpeg"));
```

There is still no guarantee that the image is loaded and none of these approaches actually tells you when it has failed.

A better solution would be to use `ImageIO` to read the image, apart from supporting more formats, it will throw an `IOException` when it fails...

```
public class Bird {
    private Image sprite;
    //...
    public Bird(Main game) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/bird.jpeg"));
```

This...

```
while(true){
    game.repaint();
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Is also very dangerous, you've started this in the `main` method, but you've take no consideration into what thread `main` might be called in.  While in "normal" operations, `main` is called by the JVM from what is known as the "main thread", there is no guarantee that this is how your `main` method is called.  It might called by another class from the context of the EDT which would cause the program to freeze.

Generally you should either use a `javax.swing.Timer` or a separate thread all together.

Comment: Than you this actually solved my issue. I'm giving my first steps into Java and graphical programming and still don't know much so sorry for that.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido It's a very common issue and can be confusing at first ;)

Answer (score 0):

To display an image which fills the entire panel, you should have the following.  You can use [`ImageIO.read(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) to read in an image from a file (you can adjust the position and size of the image inside the `paintComponent` method).  You may want to also see [Graphics.drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PictureFrame extends JComponent{

    private final Image img;


    public PictureFrame(final String file) throws IOException {
        this(new File(file));
    }

    public PictureFrame(final File file) throws IOException {
        this(ImageIO.read(file));
    }

    public PictureFrame(BufferedImage img){
        this.img = img;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Tester main:

```
public static final String TEST_FILE = "file path here";

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JComponent picture = new PictureFrame(TEST_FILE);
    frame.setContentPane(picture);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I do not intend for the picture to occupy the whole screen only a 30x30 pixels portion of it.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido I would recommend you look at the JLabel class, it works well to display images using that.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido You can specify where to place the image (in `paintComponent` method): `g.drawImage(img, x, y, 30, 30, null)`.  This will place the top left corner of the image at `(x, y,)` (in the component's coordinates) and have width and height of `30 pixels`.  If it's a sprite, I'm assuming it moves, right?  If so, this should be more appropriate than a `JLabel`.

Comment: When I try the code above nothing shows up onscreen. I guess it either is because of the way I input the image or the ImageObserver and I'm leaning towards the ImageObserver.

Comment: First, you should set the `JFrame`'s content pane to your panel: `frame.setContentPane(game);` instead of `frame.add(game);`.  My guess is that since you do not set a preferred size for this panel, when you add it to the `JFrame` it's displaying at it's "preferred" size (0 width and height).  Before calling `frame.add(...)`, call `game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));` or set the content pane like I said above.

Comment: It works for me.  Where is the file you are trying to open and what type is it?